# Find all possible values of $(7a+12,3a+5)$.

Tags: number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

If $a$ is an integer.
Find all possible values of $(7a+12,3a+5)$.

I started with:

Let $d$=$gcd(7a+12, 3a+5)$.

Then $d|7a+12$ and $d|3a+5$.

I am not sure what to do after this.

I have seen online someone saying that

$(3)(7a+12)+(-7)(3a+5)=1$

and that $d=1$ but I don't understand how.

Comment: A good first step is to try a bunch of examples.  That should tell you what the answer is...and then you can try to prove it.

Comment: @lulu The chapter in my book starts with this as an example and it just states that d=1. I am trying to understand how this came to be since this is the only example in the section and it does not explain in more details. It only gives me the definition of gcd and some propositions.

Comment: I meant, work it explicitly for several values of $a$.  That should (in this case) tell you that the answer is indeed $1$.

Comment: @lulu my apologies. I will most definitely try that. Thank you

Comment: As to the computation you have seen, note that $d\,|\,7a+12$ and $d\,|\,3a+5$ together imply that $d\,|\,\left(M\times (7a+12)+N\times (3a+5)\right)$ for any integers $M,N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But you found the very solution:   when a linear combination $ax+by=1$, we have that $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)=1$, as $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)\mid (ax+by)$, hence $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)\mid1$.

Answer (score 2):

Note that  $$(m,n)= (m,m-n)$$

Thus   $$(7a+12,3a+5)=(7a+12 -(3a+5), 3a+5)$$

$$=(4a+7, 3a+5) = (a+2,3a+5 )$$

$$= (a+2,2a+3)= (a+2,a+1)=1$$

Comment: We try to simplify using $(m,n)=(m,m−n)$ as many times as possible.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you so very much for all the help!

Comment: Thanks for attention and understanding

Answer (score 1):

If $d$ is the greatest common divisor, then $d\bigm|\bigl(3(7a+12)-7(3a+5)\bigr)$, hence $d\mid 1$.

Indeed, $7a+12=dr$ and $3a+5=ds$, for some integers $r$ and $s$. Then
$$
3(7a+12)-7(3a+5)=3dr-7ds=d(3r-7s)
$$

Removing $a$ this way should be the first thing to do. If we change the problem into finding the possible values of $\gcd(7a+12,3a+4)$, the same computation would tell us that the gcd divides
$$
3(7a+12)-7(3a+4)=8
$$
so the possible values would be $1$, $2$, $4$ or $8$. Further analysis may (perhaps) exclude some of these, or prove that there's a suitable $a$ for each of the cases.